# How to list all topics/services that are known by the server with roscpp?

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I list all topics or services that are currently known by the server with roscpp?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108176/how-to-list-all-topics/services-that-are-known-by-the-server-with-roscpp?/) by [ISibboI](https://answers.ros.org/users/9686/isibboi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-12-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2013-12-08**:
Maybe sth like rostopic list && rosservice list | grep *roscpp*? I'm not sure about the exact syntax from my mind.

**Comment by [ISibboI](https://answers.ros.org/users/9686/isibboi/) on 2013-12-08**:
Thx. With roscpp I mean using a C++ function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the services of the omnipresent rosapi node, these are equivalent to the command line statements:

rosservice call rosapi/topics
rosservice call rosapi/services

Roscpp

```
ros::ServiceClient topicfinder = n.serviceClient<rosapi::Topics>("rosapi/topics");
ros::ServiceClient servicesfinder = n.serviceClient<rosapi::Services>("rosapi/services");

rosapi::Topics topicsrv;
rosapi::Services servicessrv;

topicfinder.call(topicsrv);
servicesfinder.call(servicessrv);
```

Rospy

```
from rosapi.srv import Topics, Services

topics = rospy.ServiceProxy('/rosapi/topics', Topics)
services = rospy.ServiceProxy('/rosapi/services', Services)
topiclist = topics()
servicelist = services()
```

I've probably got some typos and mistakes in here, but that's the general gist.

---

Originally posted by [Chengarda](https://answers.ros.org/users/9541/chengarda/) with karma: 156 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) on 2017-03-07**:
It's much easier using the **Master_API**: `ros::master::V_TopicInfo topics; ros::master::getTopics(topics)`. But anyway, nice answer.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2018-03-13**:
This gives me `rospy.service.ServiceException: service [/rosapi/services] unavailable`

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2018-05-16**:
Also for me as for **Cerin** same error.....
Any ideas how to code that for rospy with the Master_API @tik0